# Create a table with counting values

Tags: r

I have a large dataset of observation of specimen in different location
The specimens have an individual name (specimen) and the location also (location).
For now, each row is a different sighting.

I would like to have a table with all of the specimen and to know in wich location they have been sighted (with the number of sithing in each locations). Each row would be a specimen and the columns would be the locations.

Is it possible to manage this?

Here is an sample of my dataset:

```
   Stops duration_m Specimen     Month      Location
     1        483   Adonia       May    Copenhagen
     2        385   Adonia       May      Saaremaa
     3        494   Adonia       May       Tallinn
     4       1955   Adonia       May St Petersburg
     5        488   Adonia       May     Stockholm
    55        480   Adonia      June      Sassnitz
    64       1330   Adonia      June          Kiel
    65        492   Adonia      June      Saaremaa
     1        482   Adonia      July       Tallinn
     2       2166   Adonia      July St Petersburg
     2        505   Adonia    August    Copenhagen
     3        486   Adonia    August      Saaremaa
     5        464   Adonia    August       Tallinn
     6       2160   Adonia    August St Petersburg
     7        491   Adonia    August     Stockholm
     8       1120   Adonia    August     Stockholm
    15        654   Adonia    August      Sassnitz
    21        361   Adonia September          Kiel
     3        495   Adonia September      Saaremaa
     4        513   Adonia September       Tallinn
     5       2001   Adonia September St Petersburg
     6        507   Adonia September     Stockholm
     8       1470   Adonia September    Copenhagen
    73        433  killuia      June    Copenhagen
    74        408  killuia      June       Tallinn
    75       2114  killuia      June St Petersburg
    76        550  killuia      June      Helsinki
    77        384      abc      June       Tallinn
    78       1116      abc      June St Petersburg
```

Comment: Your sample is completely messed up. Please edit your post following the help.

Comment: The help being, a dput of your data accompanied by a description of what you have tried and what you hope to achieve with the task at hand

Comment: Hi, I have try this: `location<-c("Helsinki", "Stockholm", "Copenhagen")
specimen<-c("Adonia", "Aidasol", "Astor")
location<-sample(location, 3000, replace=TRUE)
specimen=sample(specimen,3000,replace=TRUE)
cbind(specimen,location)
T<-table(location,specimen)
T´

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function `table` for that:

```
table(df$Specimen,df$Location)

          Copenhagen Helsinki Kiel Saaremaa Sassnitz St Petersburg Stockholm Tallinn
  abc              0        0    0        0        0             1         0       1
  Adonia           3        0    2        4        2             4         4       4
  killuia          1        1    0        0        0             1         0       1
```

**data**:

```
 df<-structure(list(Stops = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 55L, 64L, 65L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 15L, 21L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 73L, 
    74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L), duration_m = c(483L, 385L, 494L, 1955L, 
    488L, 480L, 1330L, 492L, 482L, 2166L, 505L, 486L, 464L, 2160L, 
    491L, 1120L, 654L, 361L, 495L, 513L, 2001L, 507L, 1470L, 433L, 
    408L, 2114L, 550L, 384L, 1116L), Specimen = c("Adonia", "Adonia", 
    "Adonia", "Adonia", "Adonia", "Adonia", "Adonia", "Adonia", "Adonia", 
    "Adonia", "Adonia", "Adonia", "Adonia", "Adonia", "Adonia", "Adonia", 
    "Adonia", "Adonia", "Adonia", "Adonia", "Adonia", "Adonia", "Adonia", 
    "killuia", "killuia", "killuia", "killuia", "abc", "abc"), Month = c("May", 
    "May", "May", "May", "May", "June", "June", "June", "July", "July", 
    "August", "August", "August", "August", "August", "August", "August", 
    "September", "September", "September", "September", "September", 
    "September", "June", "June", "June", "June", "June", "June"), 
        Location = c("Copenhagen", "Saaremaa", "Tallinn", "St Petersburg", 
        "Stockholm", "Sassnitz", "Kiel", "Saaremaa", "Tallinn", "St Petersburg", 
        "Copenhagen", "Saaremaa", "Tallinn", "St Petersburg", "Stockholm", 
        "Stockholm", "Sassnitz", "Kiel", "Saaremaa", "Tallinn", "St Petersburg", 
        "Stockholm", "Copenhagen", "Copenhagen", "Tallinn", "St Petersburg", 
        "Helsinki", "Tallinn", "St Petersburg")), .Names = c("Stops", 
    "duration_m", "Specimen", "Month", "Location"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -29L))
```

Comment: Working very good. Thanks a lot. Easier than I thought! Now I just have to save the dataframe in excel. Thanks!

Comment: @nif, you're welcome, glad to help. To save your data.frame, you can have a look at `write.table` or `write.csv` functions.